# Does Krishna give material success to his devotee?

Tags: krishna, artha

Aim of our life is getting Moksha. But sometimes getting material success is also needed (भूखे भजन न होय गोपाला i.e. How can one do bhakti of Krishna with a empty stomach ?)

So, does Krishna give material success to his bhakts ?
Can a person ask Krishna material success in his life to remove hardships in life so that he can do bhakti without any worries ?